# Magento2 : CSS file path loaded but CSS file not created on folder pub/static

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I have added css on custom phtml file using:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $block->getViewFileUrl('css/banner.css')?>">
```

and placed the CSS file in folder: `Magento_Theme/web/css`
When I load page and view the page content source it shows the CSS path as:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://xyz/magento-2/pub/static/version1530249778/frontend/Magento/mytheme/en_US/css/banner.css">
```

But not created any file on pub/static folder.
I have cleared the cache and run the upgrade command.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your css file in Magento_Theme folder then you should follow this code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $block->getViewFileUrl('Magento_Theme::css/banner.css')?>">
```

I hope it will works.

Comment: <?php echo $block->getViewFileUrl('css/banner.css')?> why it not created  on path  mytheme/en_US/css/ ?

Comment: I want to create the css  on path mytheme/en_US/css/

Comment: Then you should write like this:
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $block->getViewFileUrl('css/banner.css')?>"> & your css file in app/design/frontend/Vendor_Name/Theme_Name/web/css/file_name.css. folder.

Comment: After that you need to setup upgrade & deploy static content data.

Comment: M2 very complex as compare to old magento, anyway thanks

Comment: @RahulSingh Welcome, Happy to help..!!